# jQuery FancyBox, iFrame and refreshing a select in parent window?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fancybox

I am creating a shopping cart and I have to allow a user to add a new address into the system. To do this I am kicking up a FancyBox (which loads an iFrame of a form).

When the FancyBox is closed I want to refresh a list of address options in a  (basically, an AJAX query to a page with a ready prepared ). I can generate the new list no problem, but how would I refresh the  options on closing the FancyBox (I am quite happy to empty the list and reload all of them into it)?

Thank you for your time.

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close the form, the iFrame and the fancybox, it is'nt really in the parent window, is it ?

To just bind something to fancybox close event do:

```
$("#elementID").fancybox({
    onClosed: function() {
        //generate new list here
    });
});
```

add the onClosed handler to your fancybox instance, and the function will execute on fancybox close.